# I can't see the save button but see the test button only in amazon lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services

everyone!
I can't see the save button but see the test button only in amazon lambda function.
I can't know what's the reason for it.
I searched on goolge, but can't find answer.
Save button has been shown before yesterday, but today I can't see.
I hope anyone can help me.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: thanks for your attention. I'll share my lambda function screen.

Comment: Save button shows up when you have some changes for your Lambda such as timeout. try make some changes, Save button will show

Comment: when I changed something in function, unsaved changes text showed but save button didn't show.

Comment: Hey, Nghia Do! Thanks for your comment. But I can't see even save button when I have some changes in my lambda. Have you ever got this case before?

Answer (score 3):

The **user interface changed** overnight. Now you have to use **Deploy** button:

[image]

Comment: The **Save** button is still visible in my account. I wonder if this is a gradual roll-out?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Probably. They don't roll out everything at once. Its more like A/B deployments, with gradual changes to fraction of users first.

Answer (score 1):

you are right! As per the new deployment "save" button is integrated within each module. So you don't need to globally save all changes at once instead you can save only the particular setting. Likewise you can directly deploy scripts from the function code.

[image]